# Plant Identification USA zone 10

Tags: identification

I have a plant that I thought was going to be a strawberry. (No clue what kind was crown gifted to me)

It started growing so I transplanted it to a planter with a plant b that was already established. 
Now that it has grown, I'm starting to think it may not be a strawberry plant.

Anyone have any guesses? Have I been growing a nice weed?
Thanks.

NEWIST PICTURES ON TOP
New 5-11-18
[image: new bloom]
[image: starting to open up]
Older pictures

[image: close up of buds]
[image: med shot]
[image: full plant]
[image: next to active strawberry plant]

Comment: Have any Dahlias been grown in this tub...and soil?

Comment: Based on this very well photographed square stem the plant family would most likely be Laminaceae; the Mint family. If you squish a leaf or stem is there a smell?  Someone will know this plant...very familiar...take a look at this...http://www.wildflowers-and-weeds.com/Plant_Families/Lamiaceae.htm

Comment: Not that I know of, regards to the dahlias.

Comment: I forgot to test the leaves. Will do later

Comment: I have been so close...this should be incredibly easy.  I'll try tomorrow or maybe Bamboo will know!  Does this flower have white grouped ray petals with the yellow center?  Do you  remember?

Comment: Thanks Stormy.   I put up a new picture. They look like what you described to me.

Comment: Maybe a sulfur cosmos? Did a reverse image search now that I have a bloom, this was the closest I saw on a brief search.

Answer (score 1):

I think you’ve been growing a weed.

This likely to be a Senecio vulgaris, groundsell or any variations of that family.
It can be beautiful but carries diseases like club root. Not good if you have root vegetables around.

There are 100’s if species within the genus which is part of the daisy families.

The trick to know if you have a weed, is to observe how quickly they grow against other flowers. Weeds have adapted over centuries, probably millennia to grow quicker without any help from anyone.

[senecio](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senecio_vulgaris)

Answer (score 0):

(Edited, I called it Sulfer Cosmos, I believe that was for the yellow variety)

Unless someone comes in with a better answer I'm going to assume that this plant is Cosmos.

It was thriving and starting to overtake our little strawberry plant so I had to pull it out.  It has a large root system and brought with it half of the soil that was in that planter.

Final set of pictures added[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Definitely NOT a cosmos. The plant form is totally wrong.